# Php, why can't I display column results in my table using JOIN?

Tags: php, join

I have a "contacts" table like this :

```
contact_auto_inc     user_id     contact_id     
      1              1             3
      2              1             5
      3              2             1
      4              3             5
      5              3             2
      6              1             6
```

and a "user" table like this :

```
 user_id        username
     1          Simon
     2            Bill
     3            Tim
     4          Brendan
     5            Chris
     6            Noel
```

So for `user_id 1`, for example, I want to print :

```
Tim
Chris
Noel
```

How can I do this? Why is my JOIN not working ?

I am getting the error "Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp64 etc etc"

```
 $select_from_user_table = "SELECT contact_id
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN user
ON contacts.contact_id=user.user_id";

    //get the result of the above
    $result2=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_user_table); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo $row['username']  . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You are not specifying the username field to be returned by the query. SELECT contact_id, username FROM ....

Comment: Cheers jeff. I was going to say put that as an answer and I'd mark it correct but Youn Elan already did. +1 though. Would you know why the results come up twice like Tim, Tim, Chris, Chris, Noel, Noel ?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you select the columns you will be using or do a select *

```
 $select_from_user_table = "SELECT contact_id, username
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN user
ON contacts.contact_id=user.user_id";

    //get the result of the above
    $result2=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_user_table); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo $row['username']  . "<br>";
}
```